# Counting total number of rows in R based on column condition

Tags: r

So I have the following in R:

```
Name    Grade
Jerad    A
Sam      A
Paul     C
Sonia    A
Frank    C
```

And I want to count the number of rows whom has the Grade "A", in this case the output will be

```
3
```

I tried the following:

```
stud_grad <- read.csv("grades.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
nrow(stud_grad$Grade=="A")
```

But I'm getting the output:

```
NULL
```

Comment: `sum(stud_grad$Grade=="A")`

Comment: `nrow` doesn't work in your example because `stud_grad$Grade == "A"` returns a vector of TRUE/FALSE values, not a data frame. You might try `nrow(stud_grad[stud_grad$Grade == "A", ])` or `nrow(subset(stud_grad, Grade == "A"))`.